# Start service in Android Activity and nothing happened

Tags: android, android-studio, service

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mxyue.www.testdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("DemoLog", "beforetest startService");
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);
        startService(intent1);

        //stop Service
        Intent intent4 = new Intent(this,TestService.class);
        stopService(intent4);

        //restart Service

        Intent intent5 = new Intent(this,TestService.class);
        startService(intent5);

        Log.i("DemoLog", "aftertest startService");
    }
}
```

---

TestService.java

```
package com.mxyue.www.testdemo;

/**
 * Created by mxyue on 2017/8/13.
 */

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class TestService extends Service{


    @Override

    public void onCreate(){

        Log.i("DemoLog","TestService -> onCreate, Thread ID:"+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        super.onCreate();

    }


    @Override

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){

        Log.i("DemoLog","TestService -> onStartCommand, startId: "+startId+",Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        return START_STICKY;

    }


    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){

        Log.i("DemoLog","TestService -> onBind, Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        return null;

    }


    @Override

    public void onDestroy(){

        Log.i("DemoLog","TestService -> onDestroy, Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mxyue.www.testdemo">

    <application>
        ...
    </application>

    <service android:name="com.mxyue.www.testdemo.TestService"></service>

</manifest>
```

the onStartCommand not called, not have error log

some logs

- 08-13 05:51:34.935 2885-2885/? W/System: **ClassLoader referenced unknown path:** /data/app/com.mxyue.www.testdemo-1/lib/x86
- 08-13 05:51:34.937 2885-2885/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
- 08-13 05:51:34.982 2885-2885/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
- 08-13 05:51:35.183 2885-2885/? I/DemoLog: beforetest startService
- 08-13 05:51:35.187 2885-2885/? I/DemoLog: aftertest startService
- 08-13 05:51:35.490 2885-2937/com.mxyue.www.testdemo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
- 08-13 05:51:35.548 2885-2937/com.mxyue.www.testdemo W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

I found other people code like me work fine. why my code not work.

is this effect me ?

> ClassLoader referenced unknown path:

Comment: The service's class is in a different package than what you specify in the manifest.

Comment: thanks @orip I just write error in this question. My code is right, but not work.

Comment: Try to explicitly set the package: `intent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());`

Comment: I add 'intent1.setPackage(this.getPackageName());' under the 'Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);' nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

The package of class `TestService` is `package com.mxyue.www.testdemo`. Use the same also in manifest: `<service android:name="com.mxyue.www.testdemo.TestService"></service>`

Comment: sorry! I've tried it many times. I lost 'testdemo' in manifest when I write the question. The result is not change, still not start service. I edited the question for this error.